How to make country click work in "HighchartMap" (clicking on markers on the map works)?
When click on a country's territory, the handler is not called, the function is not executed. The problem is shown in the examples below:

my examle jsfiddle


my examle codesandbox + vue


The provided Sandbox isn't available. Also, please edit your question with additional details regarding your implementation, you can refer to this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Edited my question. I added a new example to "jsfiddle"

The click event won't work if the series.enableMouseTracking property is disabled. By default it is enabled, so in this case I'd recommend removing this line.
series: [{
    data: dataCountry,
    joinBy: "name",
    enableMouseTracking: false, // delete this line or set to true
    point: {
        events: {
            click() {
                alert('click country');
            }
        }
    }
}]

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f2wau5mt/
